# I can't understand Array.prootype.slice.call

Tags: javascript

```
temp = {0:'one', 1:'two', 2:'three', 3:'four',length:4};
console.log( Array.prototype.slice.call( temp, 1));

//["two", "three", "four"]
```

Why is this the result? Where is the `length` property? Shouldn't it be `["two", "three", "four", 4]` when `Array.prototype.slice.call( temp, 1)` is called?

Comment: slice() returns a new array after copying only the numeric keys of the object you called it on. Arrays have a .length property, so temp.length tells you its length.

Answer (score 3):

Simplified version of slice:

```
Array.prototype.slice = function(a, b) {
  a = a || 0
  if (a < 0) a += this.length
  b = b || this.length
  if (b < 0) b += this.length
  var ret = []
  for (var i = a; i < b; i++)
    ret.push(this[i])
  return ret
}
```

So actually slice function uses `[]` operator and `.length` property on `this`. That's how it works on arrays and array-like objects (those which have `[]` and `.length`)